# In Fitnesse I am getting an error when I try to run tests but my coworkers are able to run tests on the same scripts with no problem

Tags: fitnesse

Here's what some of it looks like:

script  com.appiancorp.ps.automatedtest.fixture.SitesFixture Could not invoke constructor for com.appiancorp.ps.automatedtest.fixture.SitesFixture[0]

setup with The instance scriptTableActor.setupWithBrowser. does not exist   CHROME  browser

set appian version to The instance scriptTableActor.setAppianVersionTo. does not exist  19.4

set appian locale to The instance scriptTableActor.setAppianLocaleTo. does not exist

I do have Chrome installed and chrome driver and I opened fitnesse through chrome.

Comment: It looks like FitNesse is unable to find the (compiled) fixture code. Can you provide some more details? For instance: are you using Java/C#,...; where should the fixture code be in your system (which directory); do you see the correct content there; does that match the configured `!path` location in FitNesse?

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, the problem is that you don't have Chrome installed.

Comment: They explicitly stated that they have Chrome installed, as well as the Chrome driver, and that they opened Fitnesse through Chrome.